# Compute the Jacobian derivative matrix of function $G ◦ F$ using the Chain Rule

Tags: chain-rule, jacobian

Given that $F(x,y)=(x^2+y, x−y)$ and $G(u,v)=(u^2, u−2v, v^2)$, compute the Jacobian derivative matrix of function $G ◦ F$ at the point $(x, y) = (1, 1)$ using the Chain Rule

[image: This is my solution to that question]

I was wondering if my solution is correct because my peer had a different solution where they found the Jacobian derivative matrix of $F(x,y)$ and $G(u,v)$ separately and then multiplied the results.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using the chain rule, yet?

Comment: So ... Anything?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you did *not use the chain rule*, but reached the **correct answer**.

It sounds like your friend *tried* to use the chain rule but made an *error* somewhere.

---

Recall that the chain rule is:

$$\mathbf J_{G\circ F}(x,y) = (\mathbf J_G\circ F(x,y))~\mathbf J_F(x,y)$$

And since $F(1,1)=(2,0)$

$$\mathbf J_{G\circ F}(1,1) = \mathbf J_G(2,0)~~\mathbf J_F(1,1)$$

Check your friend's Jacobian of $G$.  Did they make the correct variable assignment?